# Why can't carbon and nitrogen be detected in ICP-MS and ICP-OES techniques?

Tags: spectroscopy, mass-spectrometry

Why can't carbon and nitrogen be detected in ICP-MS and ICP-OES techniques?

My book says this technique is efficient for detecting multiple elements, with exception of halogens and carbon. I found somewhere that ICP is an open system, therefore it doesn't allow carbon detection. But why is that exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you say, air is allowed to enter the plasma. Air consists primarily of $\ce{N2}$ and $\ce{O2}$, and would clearly interfere with any oxygen or nitrogen in the sample. The problem is not that ICP-MS or -OES cannot detect them, the problem is air.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, the lack of carbon and nitrogen detection by ICP-OES does not propose practical problems because there are other methods to detect them.  [Combustion analysis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combustion_analysis) is one such alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Like the previous answers said, nitrogen and carbon content in the air is a contaminating factor. However according to this resource I found from 2005, it is theoretically possible to analyze nitrogen via ICP-OES by making it into a closed system.
https://www.spectroscopyonline.com/view/determination-nitrogen-and-other-essential-elements-fertilizers-icp-oes
Using combustion analysis is fine, but it's time/labor/cost intensive, where ICP-OES is relatively cheap and easy to operate. Another trade-off is that combustion analysis is fairly reliable, while ICP-OES may have to be calibrated 2-3 times over 10 hours.